# JSON Array instead of string

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Been struggling with this for hours now. Basically I need this json variable to become an array so that it can be recognised by Chart.js.

C# controller returns as follows:

```
return Json(new { DataString = json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Backend returns the following string from json results:

```
[{value:228,color:"#B3A11A"},{value:255,color:"#948299"},{value:1,color:"#5108C5"},{value:271,color:"#A86199"},{value:246,color:"#6A8869"}]
```

Which is perfectly fine, but it doesn't want to "become" an array when I assign it to the 'array' variable, in this javascript:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {

    $.get('/Stats/GetFieldJson', { fieldname: tables[i], tablename: @ViewData["tablename"]' },
function(data) {
    var array = JSON.parse(data.DataString);
    var ctx = $("#Maritalstatus").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
    new Chart(ctx).Pie(array, { scaleShowValues: true });
}, 'json');
    }
```

How can I make data.DataString into a recognisable array that matches the array syntax of the controller's output?

**Note** If I simply say:

```
var array = [{value:228,color:"#B3A11A"},{value:255,color:"#948299"},{value:1,color:"#5108C5"},{value:271,color:"#A86199"},{value:246,color:"#6A8869"}]
```

it works perfectly.

Comment: in my opinion, your controller is not returning a string, it's returning a json array, so you don't need to parse it, i think

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشم I thought so too at first, but then I saw the JSON format issue, which has bitten me before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `JSON.parse` is expecting well formed JSON, and in well formed JSON the keys need to be double quoted:

```
[{"value":228,"color":"#B3A11A"},{"value":255,"color":"#948299"},{"value":1,"color":"#5108C5"},{"value":271,"color":"#A86199"},{"value":246,"color":"#6A8869"}]
```

Comment: Nope it's worked before without the quotation marks. Needs to be that way for chart.js to work. If I make it simply var array = [{value:228,color:"#B3A11A"},{value:255,color:"#948299"},{value:1,color:"#5108C5"},{value:271,color:"#A86199"},{value:246,color:"#6A8869"}] it works perfectly

Comment: yes that works but if you use JSON.parse it has to be double quoted

Comment: Nevermind, tried it your way, worked, thank you very much (I'm a newb).

Comment: Try it:  JSON.parse('[{k:1},{k:2}]') will throw an error about 'k' being unexpected

Comment: Yea got that v was unexpected. Works now.